# How to forward static IP to the server computer in the LAN

Tags: networking, ip, local-area-network, wide-area-network, static-ip

We want to have an office server, we already have static IP. But the thing is that we need to have following structure:

```
ISP Modem
    Router
        Server
        Wireless router
```

Also I'v tried another option like:

```
ISP Modem
    Server
    Router
        Wireless router
```

But it seems to me, that router conflicts with server, therefore one of them doesn't work.

**UPDATE 1**

```
ISP Modem - STATIC IP HERE
    Server - I NEED THIS TO HAVE STATIC IP, without it i can't install DirectAdmin %)
    Router - I need to have access to the internet from Modem
        Wireless router
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server has to have internal IP, not external IP... On the point, where you are doing a NAT, you have to do rewriting of the static public IP to the server's internal IP.

Comment: check the update

Comment: Use the USB modem on the server, you will have a public IP on it and it will do routing...

Comment: Or you can use modem, which can do bridging, and than you can use PPPoE or PPPoA on the server...

Comment: Did I understood correctly? ISP->SERVER->USB MODEM->LAN ROUTER?

Comment: No. You can have ISP->USB modem without "intelligence" connected on the SERVER, server will do LAN ROUTER (NAT).

Answer (score 2):

As long as you provide your devices with individual IP addresses this is a standard setup.

If by static IP you mean your public IP, then you need to use NAT to allow your internal devices to communicate (your ISP modem should offer NAT as standard)

If you mean your server has a static IP internally, you also need to provide your other devices with IP addresses that do not conflict. Are you trying to use the same IP for server and router?

Comment: check the update